# wine and Sai.exe : HtmlHelpW HH case HH_INITIALIZE not handled

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I can't run Easy Paint Tool Sai with wine.
here is the command
**wine /home/tykayn/Documents/sai/sai.exe**

```
fixme:htmlhelp:HtmlHelpW HH case HH_INITIALIZE not handled.
fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled 0xff4d044
fixme:htmlhelp:HtmlHelpW HH case HH_UNINITIALIZE not handled.
```

i can easily run photoshop, but not sai. that is weird. Any ideas?

ubuntu 14.04.
dual boot windows 7.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I deleted SAI from PlayOnLinux because I was having issues, reinstalled in regular wine (clean prefix) and it shows me this in the terminal.